# React Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications

Is anyone able to spot why this react JS code won't compile? I am missing a brace or a parenthesis somewhere, I just can't quite work out where it is.

Are there any tools available where I could copy and paste this code and it would flag exactly where in the file I am missing some syntax?

```
function Search() {
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [imagesPerPage, setImagesPerPage] = useState(10);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchImages = async () => {
    setImages(JSONDATA);
  }

  fetchImages();
}, []);

// get current images
const indexOfLastImage = currentPage * ImagesPerPage
const indexOfFirstImage = indexOfLastImage - ImagesPerPage
const currentImages = images.slice(indexOfFirstImage, indexOfLastImage)

return (
  <Images product_serial_number={val.product_serial_number} wip_id={val.wip_id} date={val.date}>

  <div className="App">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search for wip_id, product_serial_number or date..."
      onChange={(event) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
      }}
    />
    {JSONDATA.filter((val)=>{
      if (searchTerm == "") {
        return val
      } else if (val.wip_id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
         || val.product_serial_number.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
         || val.date.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return val
      }
    }).map((val, key) => {
      return (
        <li> {val.wip_id}, | {val.product_serial_number}, | {val.date} </li>
      );
   })}
  <div/>
);
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems your three conditionals have unmatched parentheses. I'm not entirely sure what condition you are trying to check for, but it seems that is where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three lines of your snippet should be as follows:

```
      </div>
    </Images>
  );
}
```

Basically, your closing `div` tag was wrong (`<div/>` instead of `</div>`). Then you were missing closing tag for `</Images>`.

I suggest to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and its nice functionality to collapse individual elements.
Refer to the following images:

[image]

[image]